Needed result is not coming in tikz
I am trying to draw something of the following form,

I tried the following,
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \node (A) at (0,0) {\Large$\psi\chi\equiv\psi^\alpha\chi_\alpha$};
        
        \node (B) at (8,0) {\Large$\overline{\psi}\overline{\chi}\equiv\overline{\psi}_{\dot{\alpha}}\overline{\chi}^{\dot{\alpha}}$};
        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        
        \draw[<->, line width=1pt, olive] (0.7,0.5) edge[bend left=60]  (1.5,0) node[midway, above] {};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

The result of this is not as desired--

Can someone help me with this? Also, how do I make these \psi and \chi bigger? I used \Huge$\phi$ but that gave this error-- error: 705: Font U/bbold/m/n/24.88=bbold25 at 24.88pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Welcome. // Can you please give some more context why you put these formulas in nodes, rather then in your documents body? Thank you

@MS-SPO Sorry, I don't have much experience with tex, I am just trying to draw the given figure. And I came up with this. There was no need to put them in the nodes.

Bigger as in \Psi and \Chi?  Also, note that y=0 corresponds to the center of the text, as opposed to the baseline [anchor=base].

@JohnKormylo, by bigger I meant- how do I increase the font size. And I need the diagram to be as shown in my hand drawn figure, but the result that I am getting with the provided .tex code is not  desirable, how do I improve the code such that I get the desired result- that's the question.

please always provide an example of the problem, for example by default latex does not load bbold fonts, so any error is due to code you have not shown. Make a small but complete document that allows people to reproduce the problem and test answers.

Something like this? Note that it doesn't use your font choices etc. since I have no idea what you're using beyond the error.
I prefer to typeset the basic content first and add the arrows or whatever over the top, rather than trying to shove everything into nodes. Obviously, where the picture determines the layout in a diagram, you wouldn't do this. But, here, the arrows are embellishments rather than part of the primary content.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
{\Huge
\begin{align*}% probably an abuse of align* ...
  \psi\chi \equiv \psi^{\alpha\tikzmark{a1}}\chi_{\alpha\tikzmark{a2}}
  &&
  \overline{\psi}\overline{\chi}\equiv\overline{\psi}_{\dot{\alpha\tikzmark{a3}}}\overline{\chi}^{\dot{\alpha\tikzmark{a4}}}
\end{align*}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,>/.tip={Latex[bend]}]
  \foreach \i in {1,...,4} \coordinate (n\i) at (pic cs:a\i);
  \draw [<->] (n1) ++(-.5ex,1.5ex) .. controls +(2ex,1ex) and +(1ex,1ex) .. ([xshift=.5ex,yshift=-.5ex]n2);
  \draw [<->] (n3) ++(-.5ex,-.5ex) .. controls +(2ex,-1ex) and +(-0.1ex,-1ex) .. ([xshift=.25ex,yshift=-.25ex]n4);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}

Visual services are suspended for the duration of a bug in Okular in X. (Or until I figure out a workaround, alternative or Wayland.) Due to the nature of the service, replacement buses cannot be provided during this period. Apologies for the inconvenience.

I would like to add the image of the result obtained with TexMaker (I hope that @cfr sees no problem with it)


@Fermion Not from my code you're not. From some other code you've not shared, sure. But not from this.

@AndréC On the contrary, I am very grateful - thank you!
